# run time html element for spring form:errors

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-validator

If I use below code for spring form validation,

```
<form:errors path="msg" element="ul"/>
```

It returns below html run time:

```
<ul id="">Validation error message</ul>
```

But I need like below using form:errors:

```
<ul id=""><li>Validation error message</li></ul>
```

Please suggest!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Solution is as below:

```
<ul>
    <form:errors path="msg" element="li"/>
</ul>
```